# Optimization: Oj algorithms (java) versus SCIP (python)

Tags: java, python, mathematical-optimization, scip, mixed-integer-programming

Does anybody know how these 2 solvers, (Oj algorithms) from Java and SCIP for Python, relate to each other performance wise (as in: which one is the fastest), when dealing with a typical MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) problem? On first sight, I can't seem to find anything online that can point me in the right direction, and I'm curious!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't like "which is the best/fastest software for ..." questions. They are too unscientific. (Try quora). And do take a look at the solver [OptaPlanner (java, Apache License)](https://www.optaplanner.org/) too :)

Comment: Apologies, I'll try my luck at quora then (and take a look at your OptaPlanner ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

The [SCIP Optimization Suite](http://sicp.zib.de) is one of the fastest MIP and MINLP solvers available in source code. [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt), its interface to Python, might be a bit slower when constructing the model but solving times are still good since it's running the pure SCIP C library in the background.

To be honest, I have no experience with [oj! Algorithms](http://ojalgo.org/) and cannot say how good this solver is. Apparently it allows to link to Gurobi or CPLEX, so guess in this case it's mainly a modelling wrapper around those APIs providing high performance.

In the end it comes down to your modelling preferences/requirements and your specific problem instances.